# Child component doesnt updating when new props arrives

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Props goes down to child component and it doesnt trigger anything.
There is the code of both components Parent and Child.
I used `componentDidMount(){}` inside parent class.
And set up props in render child component. And inside child class I used `componentWillReceiveProps(){}`. But in child `this.setState(){}` doesnt change  state.
Guys help me with this. I can figure out why it doesnt work.

Parent:

```
class Recipes extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            recipes: [], 
            Loaded: false 
        };
        this.getRec = this.getRec.bind(this);
        this.views = this.views.bind(this);
    }

    shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState){
        console.log(nextState);
        if (nextState.Loaded !== this.state.Loaded || nextProps !== this.props){
            return true;
        }
    }
    componentDidUpdate(){

    }
    componentWillMount(){
        this.views();
    }
    componentDidMount(){
        this.getRec();
    }
    componentWillUnmount(){

    }
    componentWillUpdate(){

    }
    getRec(_){
        fetch('http://localhost:5000/recipes')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            this.setState({recipes: data, Loaded: true});
        })
        .then(data => this.render())
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
    }
    views(){
        const {recipes} = this.state;
        const howManyRecipes = recipes.length;
        const view = howManyRecipes > 0 ? 'hi' : <Route component={CreateProposal}/>
    }
    render() {
        const {recipes} = this.state;
        const howManyRecipes = recipes.length;
        console.log(howManyRecipes);
        return (
            <div>
                <div>Our community did {howManyRecipes} recipes</div>
                <RecipeList recipeList={this.state.recipes} Loaded={this.state.Loaded}/>
            </div>     
        )
    }
}
```

Child:

```
class RecipeList extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props); 
        this.state = {
            recipes: this.props.recipeList,
            loaded: this.props.Loaded
        }
        console.log(this.state.loaded);
        this.renderRec = this.renderRec.bind(this);
    }
    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
        var answ = nextProps !== this.props;
        this.setState((prevState) => {return (prevState.recipes: nextProps.recipeList.data)});
        console.log(this.state, nextProps.recipeList.data, answ);
        return answ;
    }
    // shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState){
    //     var answ = nextState.loaded !== this.state.loaded;
    //     console.log("should component update? " + answ);
    //     return answ;
    // }
    renderRec(recipe){
        return <div key={recipe.id}>{recipe.name}</div>
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <div>{this.state.recipes.length}</div>
                {this.state.recipes.map(this.renderRec)}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: you may extends PureComponent instead of Component when you try to use shouldComponentUpdate() life cycle. PureComponent reduces that things.

Comment: @Ikram-Ud-Daula Its inside parent component import {PureComponent}?

Comment: The piece that would prevent the component from updating when it receives new props is the `shouldComponentUpdate`. You should check if that returns true or false when the props change -- it most likely returns `false` when it should return `true`.

Comment: Ikram's comment isn't correct. You don't _have_ to use a `PureComponent` where data should be updated. See the [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent): 

> "React.Component doesn’t implement shouldComponentUpdate(), but React.PureComponent implements it with a shallow prop and state comparison. If your React component’s render() function renders the same result given the same props and state, you can use React.PureComponent for a performance boost in some cases."`

Comment: @SinanBolel This checkout should be inside child component which receives props? Can provide a little example code of `shouldComponentUpdate` method?

Comment: It's already inside your `Recipes` component